# Fuerte + Ubuntu 12.04 + Kinect errors

Tags: kinect, ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,
I am trying to access to the cloud point from a Kinect device using Ros Fuerte on a Ubuntu 12.04 64bit. The command roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch give me several errors. I also found several Ros Answers users with my same problems, but no one was able to find a complete solution.

Basically I found 3 kind of problems.

The first:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored process[camera_base_link3-21]: started with pid [9074]
```

This error and the similar ones are related to this Python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue14308 but I was not able to use the patch they proposed. However, it seems a minor bug that should not change anything (I hope!).

The second:

```
[ERROR] [1340647948.750262621]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/compressed/set_parameters]
[ERROR] [1340647948.758634172]: Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/depth_registered/image_rect_raw/theora/set_parameters]
```

It is related to a cyclic reference inside the files included by openni.launch. To solve this issue it is enough to comment inside the file (ros_stack)/openni_launch/launch/includes/depth_registered.launch the following code:

```
  <!-- Get all the usual depth topics -->
  <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/depth.launch"
           ns="$(arg depth_registered)">
    <arg name="manager"    value="$(arg manager)" />
    <arg name="points_xyz" value="false" /> <!-- Suppress XYZ point cloud -->
    <arg name="respawn" value="$(arg respawn)" />
  </include>
```

so, this is ok.

At last:

```
[ INFO] [1340647956.288019996]: Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1340647956.288166663]: 1. device on bus 002:08 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00365910150107A'
[ INFO] [1340647956.289262201]: Searching for device with index = 1
nodelet: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:412: boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator*() const [with T = xn::NodeInfo, boost::shared_ptr<T>::reference = xn::NodeInfo&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
[camera_nodelet_manager-1] process has died [pid 8573, exit code -6, cmd /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/nodelet_core/nodelet/bin/nodelet manager __name:=camera_nodelet_manager __log:=/home/salvo/.ros/log/1c33ed90-bee0-11e1-b0ec-f46d04509546/camera_nodelet_manager-1.log].
log file: /home/salvo/.ros/log/1c33ed90-bee0-11e1-b0ec-f46d04509546/camera_nodelet_manager-1*.log
```

I was completely not able to solve this. Could you help me? Do you have any idea? Some workaround? I found other answers here about this, but in this case no one was able to solve..

Best,
Salvo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37231/fuerte-+-ubuntu-12.04-+-kinect-errors/) by [Salvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/538/salvo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Salvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/538/salvo/) on 2012-06-25**:
no one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first two errors are not really fatal, so I'm ignoring them on my system.

the third one seems similar to what I experience on a fresh install of lubuntu 12.04 64 bit and ros fuerte.

I solved it by reverting to older versions of openni-dev and ps-engine. Using binaries for newer versions that were posted here on answers only caused more problems (ie. my camera wasn't detected at all).

step 1:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
```

step 2:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

step 3:

Open synaptic (install it if you have to) then search for openni and remove openni-dev  completely. You'll probably see version 1.5.2.23 installed.

Now select openni-dev and choose the menu item Package, Force version. Select version 1.3.2.1-4+precise1 from the menu (provided by the ppa you just added).

Install it.

Then go to Package and Lock version. You should see a red bar over the now installed openni-dev.

Then choose ps-engine (it should appear when you search for openni). Force the version for this package to 5.0.3.3-3+precise1.

install it and lock the version.

You can now install the packages ros-fuerte-openni-launch and ros-fuerte-openni-camera. The functionality should be the same as what you used to have in electric.

Now let's just hope that whatever is causing the problem gets fixed soon.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) with karma: 465 on 2012-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not sure if I found some solutions..

For the Python problem, I simply commented a line in the file /usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py , around line 806:

```
        # Thread.__block consumes an OS-level locking primitive, which
        # can never be used by a _DummyThread.  Since a _DummyThread
        # instance is immortal, that's bad, so release this resource.
#comment here:
#        del self._Thread__block
```

I am not a Python expert, so I do not know if this can cause other problems.. I think this is not exactly an elegant solution.. but it works.. so I will use this workaround and I will see if it will cause other issues.

About the last and most important problem, I simple killed the XnSensorServer program:

```
killall -s 9 XnSensorServer
```

before running openni.launch. Also here, I do not think it is the most elegant way, but it works.

However, to solve these issues I think we should wait for an update of both Python and Fuerte..

Bye,
Salvo

---

Originally posted by [Salvo](https://answers.ros.org/users/538/salvo/) with karma: 41 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sorry, this is not an answer but maybe I can help sharing my experiences:

I had the same three errors; I just ignore the first two, but the third one ALMOST disappears after installing the unstable version of openni driver, as explained [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33622/openni_launch-not-working-in-fuerte-ubuntu-precise/).
"Almost" because sometimes XnSensorServer keeps alive and you need to relaunch openni.

Hope this helps...
Jorge

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2012-06-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1